# implementation of attention r2unet network in Keras - tf 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to perform segmentation of optic disc from fundus images using attention networks. The architecture of the model is picked from "https://github.com/lixiaolei1982/Keras-Implementation-of-U-Net-R2U-Net-Attention-U-Net-Attention-R2U-Net.-"  (courtesy, credits to - lixiaolei1982).
When I track the training and validation loss, it decreases (see image below) but the training loss approaches 0 after 20 epochs. During first 20 epochs, the segmented image is completely black or completely white. I tried to normalize the predicted image. But it is the same.
Can anyone please help me rectify the issue? Is it the role of the loss function that is causing the output image to be completely black? Below is the code that uses attention net to train the images

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.backend import flatten
from skimage.exposure import equalize_hist as clhe
import network as new_model

batch_size = 32
no_epochs = 20
img_height, img_width, img_num_channels = 512, 512, 3

mdl1 = "att_r2unet"

m1 = new_model.att_r2_unet(img_height, img_width, n_label=1)

def preprocess_im(imgs):
    """Make input image values lie between -1 and 1."""
    #imgs = clhe(imgs)
    out_imgs = imgs - np.max(imgs)/2.
    out_imgs /= np.max(imgs)/2.
    return out_imgs

##

seg_train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_im)
seg_train_x = seg_train_gen.flow_from_directory(directory="../train_im",target_size=(512,512),batch_size=batch_size,color_mode="rgb",class_mode="sparse",shuffle=True,seed=30)
seg_train_y = seg_train_gen.flow_from_directory(directory="../train_gt",target_size=(512,512),batch_size=batch_size,color_mode="grayscale",class_mode="sparse",shuffle=True,seed=30)
seg_val_x = seg_train_gen.flow_from_directory(directory="../val_im",target_size=(512,512),batch_size=batch_size,color_mode="rgb",class_mode="sparse",shuffle=True,seed=30)
seg_val_y = seg_train_gen.flow_from_directory(directory="../val_gt",target_size=(512,512),batch_size=batch_size,color_mode="grayscale",class_mode="sparse",shuffle=True,seed=30)

b_iter = int(np.ceil(seg_train_x.n / batch_size))

hist = {'m1_loss': [],'m1_vloss': []}

epoch = 0
for e in range(epoch, no_epochs):
l1 = list(np.zeros(b_iter))  
    for it in range(b_iter):
        x_batch,_ = seg_train_x.next() 
        y_batch, _ = seg_train_y.next()
        loss1 = m1.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
        l1.append(loss1[0])
    xval,_ = seg_val_x.next()
    yval,_ = seg_val_y.next()
    loss2a = m1.evaluate(xval,yval, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1) 
    print('Epoch %d / %d tr_loss %.6f val_loss %.6f, ' % (e + 1, no_epochs, np.mean(l1), loss2a[0]))


    hist['m1_vloss'].append(loss2a[0])
 
    # Save best model
    if e > epoch+1:

        Eopt1 = np.min(hist['m1_vloss'][:-1])

        if hist['m1_vloss'][-1] < Eopt1:
            m1.save((save_dir+mdl1+'_best_model.h5'),overwrite=True)
            m1.save_weights((save_dir+mdl1+'_best_weights.h5'),overwrite=True)

    # save intermediate to folder results every 2 epochs
    if e % 2 == 0:

        x_plt = (xval[0] - xval[0].min()) / (xval[0].max() - xval[0].min())

        ypred = m1.predict(xval)
        fix, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(10,10))
        ax[0].imshow(x_plt)
        ax[1].imshow(yval[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
        ax[2].imshow(ypred[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
        plt.savefig((save_dir+mdl1+'e_' + str(e) + '.jpg'))
        plt.close()
  
print("Completed training...")
```

[image: training loss and validation loss snapshot]

I have tried adding Batch normalization and also modified the activation function from sigmoid to relu in final layers. Tried changing the optimizer as well. But none of these helped. In fact, sometimes the loss is negative without modifying the architecture.

Below is the sample output saved during training (Left side is the input image, the middle is ground truth and right is predicted output)
Thank you for your time.

[image: saved image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the learning rate , type of optimizer used. If it is the resultant image is coming as totally white or black may be your dataset is class imbalanced.

Some class is overpowering the other . You have to balance the dataset or use better loss function like iou, dice or focal loss.

Comment: Please fix misspelling in your post